# Bash: escape characters in backticks

Tags: bash, command-line, grep, backticks

I'm trying to escape characters within backticks in my bash command, mainly to handle spaces in filenames which cause my command to fail.

The command I have so far is:

```
grep -Li badword `grep -lr goodword *`
```

This command should result in a list of files that do not contain the word "badword" but do contain "goodword".

Comment: [Don't use backticks.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Comment: This question is on the Google's first page for "bash escape backtick", so it deserves an answer to the actual question (how to escape backticks characters in bash).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach, even if you get the escaping right, will run into problems when the number of files output by the `goodword` `grep` reaches the limits on command-line length. It is better to pipe the output of the first `grep` onto a second `grep`, like this

```
grep -lr -- goodword * | xargs grep -Li -- badword
```

This will correctly handle files with spaces in them, but it will fail if a file name has a newline in it. At least GNU `grep` and `xargs` support separating the file names with NUL bytes, like this

```
grep -lrZ -- goodword * | xargs -0 grep -Li -- badword
```

EDIT: Added double dashes `--` to `grep` invocations to avoid the case when some file names start with `-` and would be interpreted by `grep` as additional options.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm still getting some weird behavior. When I try to run this command, I get the following output:

    root@domain [/path]# grep -lrZ goodword * | xargs -0 grep -Li badword
    grep: invalid option -- k
    Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
    Try `grep --help' for more information.
    (standard input)

Comment: @Ian: Do you have a file whose name starts with a `-` in the directory? In that case, remember to also add `--` before the actual arguments to `grep`. I've modified the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

How about rewrite it to:

```
grep -lr goodword * | grep -Li badword
```

Comment: Your suggestion will output the files where the file contains `goodword` and the file _name_ does not contain `badword`

Comment: That's true; it needs an xargs... Thanks for pointing this out :)