# Exporting environment variables from script with whitespaces

Tags: bash, go, environment-variables, whitespace

Big picture of the issue: I'm creating Golang script (http://github.com/Droplr/aws-env) that will be used to secure retrieve environment variables and export them to be used for another process.

As we know, it's not easy doable as script can't export vars *outside* [1], [2].

So the way we were trying to do it, is basically [outputing export statements](https://github.com/Droplr/aws-env/blob/master/aws-env.go#L60) and then using bash backticks to run that command.

Final usage is like:

```
`aws-env` && printenv
```

where printenv should show variables exported by evaluated aws-env output (which contains "export" statements).

The problem arises with variables that contain spaces/new lines etc.

Simplifying underline code, this one works:

```
$ export A=b\ b
$ printenv | grep A=
A=b b
```

And this - not:

```
$ `echo export A=b\ b`
$ printenv | grep A=
A=b
```

I've went over other Stackoverflow discussions ([3]) but couldn't find clear answer for that problem (mostly the answer is to not use backticks, but with our overall problem we try to solve it wont be so easy...)

- [1] [Can a shell script set environment variables of the calling shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496702/can-a-shell-script-set-environment-variables-of-the-calling-shell)
- [2] https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79064/how-to-export-variables-from-a-file
- [3] [Bash: escape characters in backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479133/bash-escape-characters-in-backticks)

Comment: In the same shell. The usage of the script is like: \`aws-env\` && printenv (printenv should show env variables exported by aws-env). aws-env is just outputing  "export ..." that then should be evaluated by backticks.

Comment: Just to confirm your requirement again? what does `aws-env` expected to do? it is not clear

Comment: Shouldn't this: https://github.com/Droplr/aws-env/blob/master/aws-env.go#L60 be `fmt.Printf("export %s='%s' \n", env, value)`? Note, that in this case if your export statements contain other shell variables, they won't be extrapolated.

Comment: @favoretti unfortunately ' also does not work. `$ \`echo "export A='b b'"\` && env | grep A=
A=b`

Answer (score 0):

`eval "$(aws-env)"`

It works both with using escaped spaces and with quotes.

Answer (score -1):

If I follow this correctly, aws-env is going to output something like this:

```
export A=b\ b
export B=test
export C=this\ is\ a\ test
```

And you want those commands executed in your current shell?  If so, this should work:

```
. <(aws-env)
printenv | egrep "^[ABC]="
```

Comment: This doesn't work. If you create a simple version of his aws-env that just echos a couple of export lines, you'll find that command has no effect. I found out when trying to create a similar Python version of was-env to do the same thing and got a BrokenPipeError using he above. I then tried with a script and it seems that `.` and `source` do not work as expected with process substitution.

Comment: Isn't this what he is trying to do? 
`$ ./aws-env
export A=b\ b
export B=test
export C=this\ is\ a\ test

$ printenv | egrep &quot;^[ABC]=&quot;

$ . &lt;(./aws-env)

$ printenv | egrep &quot;^[ABC]=&quot;
C=this is a test 
B=test 
A=b b
`